# Can someone tell what's wrong with that code?

Tags: vb.net

this button is to check if there is an empty cells in the last row .
if there is filled cell the button (confirmer) will be enabled .. the application crashes when i debug

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = "true"
        DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
        DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Selected = True
        Dim c As Boolean
        Dim D As String
        Dim nbrcell As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Count - 1

        c = Confirmer.Enabled
        Do
            For i As Integer = 0 To nbrcell - 1
                D = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(i).Value
                If D <> "" Then

                    c = True
                End If
            Next
        Loop Until c = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: If it is crashing it means that it is continiously looping and never stopping. So c is never getting to TRUE. Try using string.isnullorempty instead. Seems this line of code is the problem If D <> "" Then as the condition is never met.

Comment: Please do a favor to yourself and set Option Strict On on the project properties (or better for every VB.NET project)

Comment: First of all: Use `Option Strict On`. Secondly: Please provide any exception details.

Comment: well i use option strict on now , this is my first project and i am learning the syntaxes , 
<pre> 
 Do
            For i As Integer = 0 To nbrcell - 1
                D = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(i).Value.ToString

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(D) Then

                    c = True
                End If

            Next
        Loop Until c = True
<code>

Comment: I suppose that you get a Null Reference Exception, right?

Comment: Yes Null reference exception

Comment: Seems http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to raise this

Comment: @user3540218, you should edit your question to include details that you mentioned in comments to make them become more visible

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the number of cells from the CurrentRow property.
But if there is no CurrentRow set when you run this code then the code crashes with a Null Reference Exception. (A.K.A. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object)

Instead you should use the row at NewRowIndex.

```
Dim nbrcell As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Cells.Count
```

and don't subtract 1 from the count of cells. You are doing this two times. One when you get the Count and one more time when you loop over that count (So the last cell is not  checked)

Now the loop: You never exit from that loop if the cells are all filled

```
Dim D as Object
Dim allFilled = True
For i As Integer = 0 To nbrcell - 1
    D = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(i).Value
    If D Is Nothing OrElse 
        Convert.IsDBNull(D) OrElse 
        String.IsNullOrWitheSpace(D.ToString()) Then
        allFilled = False
              Exit For ' no need to continue the loop
    End If
Next
Confirmer.Enabled = allFilled
```

I have removed the external while, the the loop is executed only using the for and it is stopped as soon as a cell with Nothing, DBNull or empty string value is found. At that point a boolean variable is set to false and applied to the Enabled property of the button. If no cells are found to be invalid then the boolen variable remains set to true and the button will be enabled.

Probably it is possible to change something in the evaluation code of the cell, but this depends on how do you fill the grid (manually or through a database data)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = "true"
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Selected = True
    Dim c As Boolean
    Dim D As Object
    Dim nbrcell As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Count - 1

    c = Confirmer.Enabled
    Do
        For i As Integer = 0 To nbrcell - 1
            D = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(i).Value
            If Not IsDBNull(D) Then

                c = True
            End If
        Next
    Loop Until c = True
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Suppose that Confirmer.Enabled starts as False and every cell is null, how do you exits from these loops?

Comment: @EldarZeynalov I think it's worth adding some explanation in your answer so OP could understand where and why he has a mistake. Also you have code formatting issue (at the top).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Confirmer.Visible = True
Confirmer.Enabled = False

DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = "true"
DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Selected = True


Dim c As Boolean = False
Dim D As Object
Dim nbrcell As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Count
Do
    For i As Integer = 0 To nbrcell - 1
        D = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.NewRowIndex).Cells(i).Value
        If Not IsDBNull(D) Then
            Confirmer.Enabled = True
            c = True
        End If
    Next
Loop Until c = True

 End Sub
```

The Problem now is that the button(confirmer) is always enabled even is the cell is empty